# SQL Casting Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTDIM (PROD_SKU, PROD_DESCRIPTION, PROD_TYPE, LGPRODUCT.BRAND_ID, BRAND_NAME, BRAND_TYPE)
    SELECT PROD_SKU, PROD_DESCRIPT, PROD_TYPE, lgproduct.BRAND_ID, BRAND_NAME, BRAND_TYPE
    FROM LGPRODUCT INNER JOIN LGBRAND ON lgproduct.brand_id = lgbrand.brand_id
```

I am getting this error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1010-MIW' to data type int.

Need help

Comment: Would you please describe your schema of `PRODUCTDIM` and `LGPRODUCT` by `desc PRODUCTDIM`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the fields in LGPRODUCT contains that string value, 1010-MIW, but that field in the [PRODUCTIM] table is an INTEGER, so it will only accept an integer number. You just need to compare the columns in each table to determine where the disconnect is.

Comment: Okay I fixed that but now I get this:                                                           Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: In the LGPRODUCT table, the PROD_SKU is varchar(15) and in PRODUCTDIM, I have PROD_SKU as varchar(15) as well

Comment: Maybe the other columns?

Comment: Gotcha, now you need to check the field lengths. It's saying you're trying to put a long character string into a column that only holds a short character string. In SSMS, expand the columns so you can see how long each field is in both databases. You'll either need to expand the column in the target database (PRODUCTIM), or truncate the LGPRODUCT field in the query, something like PROD_DESCRIPT = RIGHT(PRODUCT_DESCRIPT, 100) if the target column is 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTDIM (
                        PROD_SKU, 
                        PROD_DESCRIPTION, 
                        PROD_TYPE,
                        BRAND_ID,
                        BRAND_NAME, 
                        BRAND_TYPE
                        )

                            SELECT PROD_SKU,
                                   PROD_DESCRIPT, 
                                   PROD_TYPE, 
                                   lgproduct.BRAND_ID,
                                   BRAND_NAME, 
                                   BRAND_TYPE

                            FROM LGPRODUCT INNER JOIN LGBRAND ON LGPRODUCT .brand_id =  LGBRAND .brand_id;
```